# Auth not working with multiple database in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.8, laravel-5.7, laravel-authentication

I have two different databases: one for India and another for Canada.

I have set up the configuration in database.php file and migration and seeding working properly.

Admin model :

```
class Admin extends Authenticatable
{
  protected $connection = 'mysql_india';
}
```

Login method:

```
public function login(LoginRequest $request)
{
  $conn = 'mysql_canada';
  if($request->input('country') == '+91'){
    $conn = 'mysql_india';
  }

  $someModel = new Admin;
  $someModel->setConnection($conn);
  $model = $someModel->checkEmailExist($request->input('email'))->first();

  if($model){  // if email found
    if(Hash::check($request->input('password'),$model->password)){  // checking password
      // dd($model); // i put die here it work till here 
      Auth::guard('admin')->login($model);  // login  admin
    }
    ........
    //rest of code
  }
  ........
  //rest of code
}
```

In login, I am changing connection country wise and checking user, it is also finding user based on country but in it not Authenticating User.

If a user is from India so it is working(as I set default connection in model). but if user is from Canada it is not working ( no error just redirect to login page again).

In short default connection is working for Auth.

So to do Auth dynamically

Comment: What happens when a user is form Canada? Do you have any errors?

Comment: If user is from canada, it redirects to login page

Comment: It might be helpful to add what `checkEmailExist()` does.

Comment: It just return condition : return $query->where('email',$email);

Comment: Do you set the connection in that `$query` object or where does it come from?

Comment: before Auth, it fetch record, i put die and get object, just issue is with Auth

Comment: After Auth line, it redirect to login page